# Как проверить, пустой ли observable?

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, pipes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lcsphp

Не понимаю, как сделать проверку на observable, если он пустой:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of bookings$ | filterByStatus: 'pending' | async; trackBy: trackById" >
```

Это работает, пока существуют заказы со стасусом "pending". Но если таких нет, показывает ошибку "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined", что логично.

Вот как я фильтрую это в pipe:

```
    @Pipe({
      name: 'filterByStatus'
    })
    export class FilterByStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(orders$: Observable, status: string): Observable {
        return orders$
          .pipe(map((o: Order[]) =>
            o.filter(o => o.status == status)))
      }
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: лучше всего поменяй местами пайпы, чтоб вначале шел `async`, он тебе раскроет значение из потока. В следующем пайпе проверяй на `null` обязательно, потому что если поток асинхронный, то `async` генерирует `null` как _initial value_. С _unwrapped_ значением из потока тебе будет намного легче работать и дебажить всю эту кухню

Comment: @overthesanity Да, это было бы проще всего, но тогда пайп фильтрует заказы только при загрузке страницы, а не автоматически, когда я меняю им статус на 'active' или 'completed' например

Comment: `transform` будет вызываться всегда, когда меняется либо `orders$`, либо `status`, `orders$` вряд ли меняется, я могу предположить что это либо `Subject || BehaviorSubject`. Так что без разницы на каком месте он стоит, был бы рабочий stackblitz - я б тебе  показал.

Comment: @overthesanity, добавила ссылку на stackblitz. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, если сможете

Comment: @overthesanity и вот тут https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z1kuox сделала, как вы писали выше, не фильтрует автоматичеки (

Comment: смотри, у тебя есть такая строчка кода в сервисе `this.bookingsSubject.next(this.bookings);`. `transform` вызывается когда меняется один из аргументом иммутабельно, т.е. под капотом он делает проверку `if (lastOrders !== newOrders) pipe.transform(newOrders)`. Если ее поменять на `this.bookingsSubject.next([...this.bookings]);`, то фильтрация работает

Comment: Вау!!...)))) @overthesanity, спасибо огроменное! это решает для меня много подобных ситуаций)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте оператор filter() внутри pipe() перед вызовом оператора map()

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'filterByStatus'
    })
    export class FilterByStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(orders$: Observable, status: string): Observable {
        return orders$
          .pipe(
           filter(o => !!o),
           map((o: Order[]) =>
            o.filter(o => o.status == status))
          )
      }
    }
```

Comment: не понимаю, как это должно работать( Что дает  оператор filter() внутри pipe() перед вызовом оператора map() ? В этом примере подчеркивает filter как ошибку

Comment: filter() проверяет соответствие значению в стриме условию и не пропускает значения которые не проходят валидацию

Comment: Я исправил ответ, у меня не было приведения значения к Boolean

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось гораздо проще

```
  transform(orders$: Observable, status: string): Observable {
    return orders$
      .pipe(map((orders: Order[]) => {
        if (orders) return orders.filter(o => o.status == status)
      }))
  }
```